# How to get the pixels on an Active contour in python?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, contour, image-segmentation, edge-detection

I'm trying to implement the active contours by Chan-Vese Algorithm, but with an element of Region-based localized energies. So i need to implement a function **B** such that it is patch on the pixels of the active contour to compare the intensities on the neighbouring pixels, interior and exterior as shown in image. [The red circle in the image defines the function B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgB0z.jpg)

So the condition is such that all the points inside the active contour and within the circle given by fucntion B is given '1' and all the points outside Active-contour and inside the B is given '0'.

I need to get the final result in an array. Please help.